# how to return the value of a scalar function in db2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a db2 function returning an integer. As per my limited knowledge the only way to see this function working is using to return column in a query like the example below.

Is there a way to display a return value of a function given a parameter withoyt building up a more complex query?

Example

I have a function

```
  myfoo(index integer) returns integer ...
```

And I am using it in a more complex quewry like

```
  select myIndex, myfoo(myIndex), myValue from MyTable...
```

If I try to get the following

```
  select from myfoo(3)
```

it will not work.

Is there any db2 function to print out the return value of that function without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the compatibility vector, you can even use Oracle's Dual table.    http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052874.html

Also, you can use the 'values' sentence. For example,

```
values myfoo(myIndex)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT myfoo(3) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 is a special "dummy" table that contains a single row, the equivalent of Oracle's DUAL.